# How to use gcc correctly from the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, undefined-reference

I'm try to compile a .c file from the terminal using gcc. The file includes a personal library where a function is defined. This library.h and the .c file are in the same directory.

I get the following message error

```
undefined reference to `function'"
```

Should I use another argument as:

```
gcc -o nameoutput filename
```

or should I place the library.h in another directory?

Comment: For reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `library.c`, `library.h` and `main.c` in your current working directory:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c library.c -o my_program
```

and then to run it:

```
$ ./my_program
```

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined reference" means that the linker can't find the object file containing the compiled body of `function`; it doesn't have anything to do with the .h file.

I sounds like you have a situation where `library.h` and `library.c` are in one directory, and `main.c` is in a different directory.  If that's the case, then your command line will need to look something like this:

```
gcc -o program -I /path/to/library main.c /path/to/library/library.c
```

`-I /path/to/library` means that gcc will look for .h files in that path as well as the standard include paths.  That also allows you to write

```
#include "library.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "/path/to/library/library.h"
```

in any code that needs it.